# Reset INCREMENT VALUE For Identity Column using T-SQL Script

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I Need Change Increment Value for Identity Column

For Example 
I have create table Test Table with Identity Column

```
Create Table test 
(
 Id Int Identity(1,1)
,Name Varchar(200)
)
```

Now it is easy to Reseed the start value of Identity Column using

```
DBCC CheckIdent('TEST',Reseed,100)
```

But I want to change the Increment value **1 to 10**
is there any sql command that will work ..

While changing from SSMS 2016 I get this error

[image]

Comment: I believe through the `UI` in `SSMS`, design the table and increase the identity column increment value there to what you want. Save the table.

Comment: @WEI_DBA: I have try that but it is not working for me..:(

Comment: I just did that and it worked for me.

Comment: is your Table have data ? - @WEI_DBA

Comment: Yes it has data.

Comment: I have updated My Question with Error snap - @WEI_DBA

Comment: Go to Tools > Options > Designers and uncheck `Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation`.

Comment: That's Works ..!! But what about TSQL script -@WEI_DBA

Comment: I turned on Profiler when I modified the Identity column and SQL Server is creating a temp table with the new identity increment and dropping the old table and renaming the new one back to the old name. So it's as SqlZim says in his answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the increment you need to drop the existing `identity()` column and add a new column.

```
alter table test drop column Id;
alter table test add Id int identity(100,10);
```

If you want to keep existing values, then you will need to create a new table, insert the existing rows with `identity_insert on`, drop the old table, and rename the new table.

For example:

```
create table test (id int identity(1,1), name varchar(200) default '')
insert into test default values
insert into test default values

create table new_test (id int identity(100,10), name varchar(200) default '');

set identity_insert new_test on;
  insert into new_test (id,name)
  select id,name from test
set identity_insert new_test off;

drop table test;

exec sp_rename 'new_test','test';

insert into test default values;
insert into test default values;

select * from test;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/XDE9355

returns:

```
+-----+------+
| id  | name |
+-----+------+
|   1 |      |
|   2 |      |
| 100 |      |
| 110 |      |
+-----+------+
```

Comment: Thanks for Replying @sqlzim but I don't want to Drop and Recreate the table .Is there any alternate  for this

Comment: @Dhaval Not that I am aware of. Using the SSMS table designer as WEI_DBA suggested generates code that drops and recreates the table for this operation as well.